# Excel VBA: Modal form acts Modeless after Application.InputBox is called

Tags: excel, vba

I have a MODAL form formX that contains a button cmdChangeWeight. User clicks cmdChangeWeight and enters a weight in Type 1 Application.InputBox, then clicks OK or CANCEL to return to formX.

The problem is that after the Type 1 Application.InputBox is opened the user can then click on and scroll around my worksheet, even after they click OK or Cancel, though my MODAL form is still open.  My expectation is that after the input is done and control passes back to formX, then the user can no longer touch the underlying worksheet.

' The problem seems to be on the Application.InputBox Statement. After that runs, I am then able to click on worksheet cells, but not before. How can InputBox make my form act modeless when it's always modal?  I have another Application.InputBox (type 8) call on another button of the same form, but when it closes, the ability to touch the worksheet ends (expected).

```
   On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Prompt user for new weight. Allow cancel.
    vResponse = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="ID " & sID & ", " & _
        Format(dDate, gsDATE_DISPLAY_FORMAT) & ", " & _
        sProduct & vbCrLf & _
        "Available = " & Format(Me.lstSource.List(iItemNum, 4), "0.00") & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter new weight (in lbs)", _
        Title:="Change Weight", Default:=Format(rOldWeight, "0.00"), type:=1)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

' I tried changing the InputBox line to this and I have the same problem.

```
vResponse = Application.InputBox("Hi", type:=1)
```

' Then I tried changing from Application.InputBox to InputBox. THIS WORKED to protect my worksheet, but it would not be an acceptable solution in all cases. I still would like to know the real answer.

```
vResponse = InputBox(Prompt:="ID " & sID & ", " & _
                    Format(dDate, gsDATE_DISPLAY_FORMAT) & ", " & _
                    sProduct & vbCrLf & _
                    "Available = " & Format(Me.lstSource.List(iItemNum, 4), "0.00")  & _
                    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    "Enter new weight (in lbs)", _
                    Title:="Change Weight", Default:=Format(rOldWeight, "0.00"))
```

How is it possible that my Modal form allows the worksheet to be scrollable and clickable after Application.InputBox is closed?

Thanks!
Shari

(P.S. This is a reposting because I got a lot further in the troubleshooting and needed you folks to take another look.)

Comment: ten years past, nobody answer. I have the same problem. Once the application.inputbox is launched, any cell is clickable as if the userform become vbmodeless. For the time being, i just use : inputbox (without `application.`), as you suggested. This won't make cell is clickable. Thanks.